# finding a string in a large text and return the paragraph which the string is in that paragraph

Tags: python, string-search

Hi I wanna search a string in a large text and return the paragraph which involve the string. (In Python)

Here is the example of the data that need to be searched:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/obophenotype/human-phenotype-ontology/master/hp.obo

In this example I want to search for the string 'chest pain' and there are paragraphs involving it. How I code to get the whole paragraph starting at *[TERM]* and ending at the beginning of next *[TERM]*

Comment: Which programming language do you know of? (specify also in the tags please). Did you try something for yourself yet?

Comment: python and I use Colab as a platform.

Comment: It is simply can be done if we search for a string and return the line which includes the string. But I have no clue how to return the whole paragraph.